# ASPX project where do I find the logic behind the front end code

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

Hello I'm fairly new to developing in ASPX. I'm having a little trouble understanding where the data/logic is coming in from. Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Register.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RegisterRequest.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.LosAngeles.Web.Application.Register.RegisterRequest" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <br>
        <h2 style="margin: 5px;">
            <font color="#993333">Register Request</font>
        </h2>
        <table border="0" style="margin: 5px;">
           
            <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: left;">
                    <b>User Name:</b>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="JurorName" runat="server"> UserName</asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <b>Register Type:</b>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="RegisterType" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <br />
    </asp:Content>
```

Here is my question in the `DropDownList` it's pulling information I'm assuming from the `RegisterType` ID. However, where do I find where this is coming from, when I do a search through the whole project for `RegisterType` this is the only instance where it is being called. I did notice on line one there is a  `CodeBehind="RegisterRequest.aspx.cs"` and `Inherits="Test.LosAngeles.Web.Application.Register.RegisterRequest"` however I can't find those files anywhere in the project. When I googled what CodeBehind is doesn't seem like I'm looking for the right thing.

I just need some direction on where usually the backend logic gets stored. This way I know here `UserName` and `RegisterType` are being pulled in from or where they are being set. I understand this question might be too vague so I apologize in advance. Would just like to know where you typically would look for the backend code for this I'm assuming it's in C#.

Comment: so if you select your aspx file in VS and hit F7 does it not jump to the code behind? (Or right-click the file in VS Solution Explorer and select "View Code".)

Comment: Well, you need visual studio, and you need the web application. Without that, then you can't for any practical purposes work on that site. As noted, while the page is in design mode in VS, then right click  and choose code - that will jump to the so called "code behind" view, and at that point you should see the code. So how this works is actually VERY similar to desktop software. You have the forms designer, and then you can jump to the code part. But for web land, your markup + forms designer is web markup, and then code behind is plane jane vb.net, or c# code.

Comment: @SimonWilson thank you, let me give that a try. I was using Code. Let me try opening the project in VS.

Comment: Not sure if I'd set about learning aspx now; it's defunct. MVC at least, if not Blazor

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal so I went to open folder instead of open Project/Solution. I found the ASPX file, right now it the bottom left corner I see Design, Split, Code. I'm under code. I can't find the "View Code" I tried right clicking on the file but don't see that option not even grayed out

Comment: You want to open the project first - not a indivduial aspx file. There should be a "sln" file, but it depends. If no "sln" file exists, then you need in VS to choose "open web site". But either way, your project explore should show the pages in a pane as a tree. You can then double click on any page. So don't use VS to open a page direct - open the project (sln file), or use open web site if no "sln" file exists. From that point on, you REALLY have to open the web pages from VS and always from the project explorer.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal thank you for all your help. There is no `sln` file. I was able to open it as a website. Now when I right click the file I do see "View Code" however it just shows the code I showed you above. It doesn't jump to no code behind. Very weird

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal not sure if this helps. This folder is on my local computer. However If I drag this folder to IIS and create a website, it loads up like a charm with everything running and working. Not sure if this is even relevant

Comment: When you publish a .net site, the compilers and code system compiles code behind and spits out everything else into a folder. That folder can then simply copied or even FTP to the web server.  I mean, if you look in that folder, you should see files with aspx, and then other files with aspx.vb, or aspx.cs.  So you may well not have the source code. You MUST have those files present (.vb, or .cs).  If you see those files, then you are ok. (thus look for .sln, or csproj, or vbproj and open that. During development, VS should have setup a IIS express for you to use - so you don't need full IIS

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal it's weird I copied the whole and don't see any .vb or .cs files present. Even when I search it on the IIS production server I don't see any of those files. However, I do see a .vs folder. Here is a screenshot `https://ibb.co/m8mFCyJ`

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal as for `.csproj` I found a few files that contain that name for example. `edge-cs.csproj` or `BookService.csproj`

Comment: You might not have original project and source. Depends if this is .net web forms project or a newer MVC one. Try creating  brand new project. - take a look at the resulting folders. Spend time to get familiar with how this works. Create a new project - then take a look at the files and folders. And after you create that test project - hit f5 in vs to run it - it should run. So as noted, when you publish that web app, then a resulting folder may well not have source code anymore (it depends on the type of web project created. Some will not have source code and only .dll's in the bin folder.

Comment: but, try opening the csproj with vs - see if that works, but better yet, create a new project - play and have some fun - and also look at the files created.

Answer (score 0):

When you open up the project in Visual Studio (VS) and you open up the .aspx file and you want to access the .aspx.cs file (CodeBehind), just use the F7 key on your keyboard and VS will take you to the .aspx.cs file.